# I want to update state in model based on state in another model in odoo

Tags: python, odoo, odoo-11

I want to update state in model based on state in another model in odoo.

I try to update employee state in employee model:

```
where work_order_state= "progress" set employee_state="unavailable"
```

I try onchange function but it use less and try update function but it not return anything and try update/create same things
This is my first question in stack overflow any one can help me.

**Python**:

```
from typing import ByteString
from odoo import models, fields, api,exceptions, _
from odoo.exceptions import ValidationError, UserError

""" Defines manufacturing resource """

class MrpWorkcenter(models.Model):
    _inherit = 'mrp.workcenter'
    _description = 'Work Center'
    
    employee_ids = fields.One2many('hr.employee', 'employee_id', string="Resource")
    
    workcenter_id = fields.Many2one("mrp.workorder")  
    employee_id = fields.Many2one('hr.employee', string="Name")
    resource_state = fields.Many2one('hr.employee', string="State")  

class Employee(models.Model):
    _inherit = "hr.employee"
    _description = "Employee"

   
    is_resource = fields.Boolean('Resource')
    employee_id = fields.Many2one('mrp.workcente', string="Resource")
    resource_state = fields.Selection([
        ('available', 'Available'),
        ('unavailable', 'Unavailable')],
         string='State')
    workcenter_ids = fields.One2many("mrp.workcenter", 'employee_id',string="Work Center")
    workorder_id = fields.Many2one("mrp.workorder", string="Resource")


    @api.multi
    def _update_state(self, vals):
        for res in self:
            record_to_update= self.env['hr.employee'].search()
            if record_to_update.exists():
                for rtn in self:
                    record_to_search= self.env['mrp.workorder'].search([('state', '=','progress')])
                    if record_to_search.exists():
                        vals={
                        'resource_state':'unavailable'
                            }
                        record_to_update.write(vals)
                        return rtn

        return res

class ManufacurWorkorder(models.Model):
    _inherit = 'mrp.workorder'
    _description = 'Work Order'

            
    workcenter_id = fields.Many2one("mrp.workcenter")
    employee_ids = fields.Many2many('hr.employee', string="Resource")
    state = fields.Selection([
        ('pending', 'Pending'),
        ('ready', 'Ready'),
        ('progress', 'In Progress'),
        ('done', 'Finished'),
        ('cancel', 'Cancelled')], string='Status',
        default='pending')
    workorder_id = fields.Many2one('mrp.workorder')
```

**XML**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<odoo>
  <data>

    <!-- Created by Mehad Mregany at 01022021 10:30 am -->
     <!-- Edited  by Mehad Mregany at 07022021 08:30 am -->

                 <!-- Manufacture Resource -->

<record id="manufacture_resource_hr_form_id" model="ir.ui.view">
    <field name="name">hr.employee.form</field>
    <field name="model">hr.employee</field>
    <field name="inherit_id" ref="hr.view_employee_form"/>
    <field name="arch" type="xml">
        <field name="mobile_phone"  position="replace">
            <field name="is_resource"/>
        </field>
        <field name="work_phone" position="replace">
            <field name="resource_state" attrs="{'invisible':[('is_resource', '=', False)]}"/>
        </field>
        <field name="coach_id" position="replace">
              <field name="workcenter_ids" widget="many2many_tags"
               attrs="{'invisible':[('is_resource', '=', False)]}"
               options="{'no_create':True,'no_create':True }"/>
        </field>
    </field>
</record>

<record id="manufacture_resource_hr_tree_id" model="ir.ui.view">
          <field name="name">hr.employee.tree</field>
          <field name="model">hr.employee</field>
          <field name="inherit_id" ref="hr.view_employee_tree"/>
          <field name="arch" type="xml">
              <field name="name" position="after">
                  <field name="is_resource"/>
              </field>
               <field name="work_phone" position="replace">
                  <field name="resource_state"/>
              </field>
          </field>
</record>

<record id="manufacture_resource_workorder_form_id" model="ir.ui.view">
    <field name="name">mrp.workorder.form</field>
    <field name="model">mrp.workorder</field>
    <field name="inherit_id" ref="mrp.mrp_production_workcenter_form_view_inherit"/>
    <field name="arch" type="xml">
    
    <notebook>
     <page string="Resource">
        <field name="employee_ids" 
        domain="[('resource_state','=','available'), ('is_resource','=','True')]">
            <tree string="Resource" editable="bottom"> 
                <field string="Employee" name="name" />               
            </tree>
        </field>
     </page>
    </notebook>
    </field>
</record>

  </data>
</odoo>
```

Answer (score 0):

as i did get from your distributed code that you want to update state in hr.employee based state in mrp.workorder
you can update your code to look like this first move your code to be in mrp.workorder

```
@api.onchange('state')
def update_state(self, vals):
    record_to_update= self.env['hr.employee'].search([('employee_id', 'in', self.employee_ids)])
    if record_to_update and self.state == 'progress':
        self.env['hr.employee'].write({'resource_state': 'unavailable'})
```

Comment: thanks for replay ... i try this onchange but it not update the resource_state

Comment: you can remove "record_to_update" condition and try it with only state=='progress' condition .. more important when doing the unit testing please motivate the onchange decorator ..